# Django MultipleChoiceField and model instance

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to pass a queryset to form's field. I am trying to display developers that are filtered by current project (I am getting current project by slug). Unfortunately, I am getting an error, that `global name 'project' is not defined`. It seems that the argument doesn't pass from form instance to the forms.py file or something...

This is my forms.py:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('iteration', 'story', 'description',  )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = kwargs.pop('project')
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['developer'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Developer.objects.filter(project = project)) # this is where I want my objects to filter
```

This is how I am initialising the form:

```
project = Project.objects.get(user=user, slug=slug)
taskForm = TaskForm(request.POST, project = project)
```

This is the model:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
task = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
```

I think that the solution is pretty obvious, but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call variable project which is not defined. 
Use **self.project** instead.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.project = kwargs.pop('project')
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['developer'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Developer.objects.filter(project = self.project))
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am still getting an error, that `global name 'project' is not defined`. The form instance is `taskForm = TaskForm(request.POST, project = project)`, so it SHOULD work, I don't understand

Comment: @Eimantas did You try to write as I said? The problem is in constructor. I mean in `__init__()` function. You assign `kwargs.pop('project')` to `self.project`. So, you need to write `queryset = Developer.objects.filter(project = self.project)` in brackets, not `queryset = Developer.objects.filter(project = project)`

Comment: Its seems that because I was in a hurry I missed the `.self` part and thought that I have already tried your suggestion earlier, but thank you very much, the code works perfectly now :) I've got to focus much more into little details..